# Delete read-only Zend row

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table, delete-row

What causes a row (`Zend_Db_Table_Row`) to be set to "`readOnly`?" I'm having trouble deleting rows in a loop:

```
// this is set to some integers
$ids = array();

// get the results
$results = $table->fetchAll($select);

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $value = $result->value;
    if (!in_array($value, $ids))
    {
        // throws a "row is read-only" error
        $result->delete();
    }   
}
```

Here's my select:

```
$table = $options->joinModel;
$select = $table->select();
$select->from($table->getTableName(), array("id", "value" => $options->joinForeignKey))
       ->where("`{$options->foreignKey}` = ?", $row->id)
       ->group($options->joinForeignKey);
```

I want to delete the row's that aren't in the $ids array, but it throws an error saying the row is read only. I haven't set that flag or done anything with the row. Any idea why it's read-only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A row is readOnly if the `$select` is such that prevents you from directly mapping fields back to a single origin row.

For example, if the `$select` involves a `JOIN` or a `GROUP BY`, it's not clear which row(s) would be affected if you change a value of a field in the row object.

You might say "*I* know which row is the source, why can't `Zend_Db_Table_Row` tell?"  But there are many corner cases, so it's a hard problem to solve in general.

Keep in mind all of `Zend_Db` is under 3000 lines of code.  It can't have a lot of magic in it.

A row object can also be readOnly if you've serialized and then deserialized it.

Comment: Oh, ok, so basically... selecting a row "AS value" ...the row's wouldn't be sure that value was a real field or not. Makes sense. I can get away without the alias, so it's an easy fix. Great answer!

Comment: Yes, and also because you `GROUP BY joinForeignKey`, then in theory there could be multiple rows in the group.  So if you were to `$row->id = 1234`, which row in the table should it update?

Comment: Good point. I'm going to take that group out. Should be working now :) Thanks a mil, Bill.